# Transform old iphone entry into new one for docking station

Tags: iphone, lightning

I have a docking station that works that plays music by connecting an (old) iPhone 3. Since I don't want do throw away a working music station, I was wondering if there exist a cable that would allow me to connect instead my new iPhone 5 to it.

Answer (score 1):

[This Lightning to 30-pin adapter from Apple](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD823AM/A/lightning-to-30-pin-adapter) should work just fine.